# LoggerAdapter does not log extra

Tags: python, logging

When running the following code:

```
import logging
from logging import LoggerAdapter
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

def f():
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    adapter = LoggerAdapter(logger=logger, extra={"client_id": "132"})
    adapter.info("test")


if __name__=="__main__":
    f()
```

I get the following output:

```
INFO:__main__:test
```

So the extra dictionary is not logged. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the extra param in formatter.

```py
FORMAT = "%(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(message)s:{\"client_id\": %(client_id)s}"
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format=FORMAT)
```